# iOS, objc, swift, fail to create an extension on objc file

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to extend my objc class:

```objectivec
#import "Name-Swift-Import.h"

@interface RequestDateOptionViewCell () <DatePickerViewDelegate>
```

Then I extend the class but in Swift:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@objc extension RequestDateOptionViewCell: AXCustomContentProvider {
    public var accessibilityCustomContent: [AXCustomContent]! {
        get {
            [
                
            ]
        }
        set(accessibilityCustomContent) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Then I compile to see the results.
The issue appears within the autogenerated file:

```objectivec
@class AXCustomContent;

SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(ios,introduced=14.0)
@interface RequestDateOptionViewCell (SWIFT_EXTENSION(NAME)) <AXCustomContentProvider>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<AXCustomContent *> * _Null_unspecified accessibilityCustomContent;
@end
```

error message:

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'RequestDateOptionViewCell'

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: seem like your bridging header from objc->swift doesnt work or `RequestDateOptionViewCell` interface is not exposed in it so swift can't see it and therefore must complain it cannot find the interface to extend it. In this case it is much easier to extend it in objc.

Comment: also if `#import "Name-Swift-Import.h"` is your swift exposed stuff bridging back to objc, it should be declared in implementation file, despite it is asking for a header file.

Answer (score 0):

Got the following to compile if you want to double check for differences (replace `<your_module>` with name of your app's module)

`<your_module>-Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import "RequestDateOptionViewCell.h"
```

`DatePickerViewDelegate.swift`

```
@objc
protocol DatePickerViewDelegate {
}
```

`RequestDateOptionViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RequestDateOptionViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

`RequestDateOptionViewCell.m`

```
#import "RequestDateOptionViewCell.h"
#import "<your_module>-Swift.h"

@interface RequestDateOptionViewCell () <DatePickerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation RequestDateOptionViewCell

@end
```

`RequestDateOptionViewCell+Accessibility.swift`

```
import Accessibility

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@objc
extension RequestDateOptionViewCell: AXCustomContentProvider {
    public var accessibilityCustomContent: [AXCustomContent]! {
        get { [] }
        set(accessibilityCustomContent) { print("setting accessibility content") }
    }
}
```